# Android Processes and Memory

Tags: android, memory, process

So I have looked around and in the docs to see exactly how I would go about defining a separate process for my application. So far I have in the manifest

```
<receiver android:name="edu.sc.test.GeofenceReceiver"
              android:exported="false"
              android:enabled="true"
              android:process=":GeofenceReceiver"
        >
    </receiver>
```

I understand that the colon in the process name runs the process in its own memory, however my application still seems to have the same problems since the dalvik seems to be running out of memory in the logcat. My app does a lot of non ui work in the background but the non ui work seems to be slowing the app down, so I from what I understand i need a process to separate the ui work from the background work. How do I go about creating a separate private process so that the memory is not used up?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to determine what the source of your memory problems is, and try to address that? "so I from what I understand i need a process to separate the ui work from the background work" -- not usually.

Comment: @CommonsWare Well when I said "running out of memory" the dalvik constantly says "....GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2048K, 35% free 17388K/26664K, paused 26ms.." but it doesnt throw an out of memory error, which from what I understand means that the memory is being used up. Maybe Im looking in the wrong place. Im trying to find the best way to separate the UI from the background work without my app slowing down.

Comment: "Im trying to find the best way to separate the UI from the background work without my app slowing down" -- then use Traceview to figure out exactly where your problem is. You might also consider using DDMS' allocation tracker to determine where your memory churn is coming from.